# Where is "0" coming from in my unzip() return? How do we create the inner loop where the indices are flipped around?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Coding Challenge:

Write a function, unzip, which accepts a matrix of nRows rows and nCol columns. It should return a new array, of numCol rows and numRows columns, which regroups elements.

```
unzip([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
]);
// [[1,3],[2,4]]

unzip([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
]);
// [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

unzip([["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]);
// [['a','b','c']]
```

I'm not sure how to implement the inner forloop logic.

My thought process:

```
results[0][0] = arr[0][0] // outer
results[0][1] = arr[1][0] // inner (flipped)
results[1][0] = arr[0][1] // inner (flipped)
results[1][1] = arr[1][1] // outer
```

Attempt:

Prepopulate the results array with 0s and then insert the correct values

```
unzip([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);

function unzip(arr) {
  const results = [];
  const row = arr[0].length;
  const col = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    results.push([0, 0]);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    results[i][i] = arr[i][i];
    for (let j = results.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      results[i][j] = arr[j][i];
    }
  }


  return results;
} // [ [1, 3], [0, 4]], correct: [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Where in the world is this "0" coming from in my return? There is no 0 in the original array

Comment: Looking at your thought process: it looks like you're thinking in terms of square matrices? The exercise is asking you to turn a 2D array with n rows and m columns into a 2D array with m rows and n columns, with original elements (i,j) now at (j,i) - applied to your thought process code: those (0,0) and (1,1) have also been flipped. With that said: why are you pushing `[0,0]` into results, when `arr` can be "any size x any size"? (why are you adding anything at all? Just make sure that `result[i]` is an array, and set the new `result[i][j]` values as you walk through the data)

Comment: Why are you doing ``results.push([0, 0]);``?  I mean, for your example, ok, but you don't know that you'll have always 2 columns, do you?

Comment: I think this is a little confusing `const row = arr[0].length; const col = arr.length;` maybe it's more clear as `const cols = arr[0].length;  const rows = arr.length;` I'm saying this because once you get that, it's all about two nested for loops https://jsfiddle.net/y5ms6bta/3/

Comment: I tend to get one example working, and then figure out how to change it to get all the examples working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Mike said in comment (square matrix), your code starts from a result full of 0s. And then does as if result was filled with the initial value, and swapping them.

I mean, your double loop excludes cases where j<i.
And yet, it only affects `result[i][j]`. So, how `result[i][j]` are supposed to get non-0 values when j<i?

Keeping your logic, as much as possible

```js
function unzip(arr) {
  const results = [];
  const row = arr[0].length;
  const col = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    results.push(new Array(col).fill(0));
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (let j = col - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      results[i][j] = arr[j][i];
    }
  }


  return results;
}
```

Note that I also removed the specific treatment for `result[i][i]`, which has no reason to be. It is just one value among others. And which fails if matrix is not square. And used your variable row and col, to avoid also assuming in the loop that it is square.

A shorter version (without using your logic)

```js
function unzip(arr){
    result=[];
    for(let i=0; i<arr[0].length; i++){
        result.push(arr.map((l)=>l[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Each line of result is the ith column of arr, which you can get by getting `l[i]` with l being all lines of arr. Which is what `arr.map((l)=>l[i])` does.

Comment: A very elegant solution. Thank you for teaching me

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done very elegantly with a double-`map`:

```js
const unzip = m => 
  (m [0] || []) .map ((c, i) => m .map (r => r [i]))

console .log (unzip ([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
console .log (unzip ([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
console .log (unzip ([["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We map over the first row (or an empty array if the input is empty), and for each column index, we return the result of mapping over the rows, extracting the cell at the given index from each row.

I usually call this function [`transpose`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20transpose), because for non-ragged, dense 2-d arrays it serves as a matrix transposition function.  But `unzip` is a good name too.